# Pick the month closest to a list of set months

Tags: bash

In a bash script, I have a date in the `$extracted_date` variable that is scraped from a file.

The date from the file could be any date, but I want to check it against a list of known dates, and pick the closest matching date in the past to display instead.

This is what I have so far. It converts everything to seconds since epoch to determine if the scraped date is after or before a known date, but that's as far as I got.

Is there a method to "pick" the date it matches closest to from the list? Is this possible in bash?

```
#!/bin/bash

known_dates=(
    "$(date --date '1 January this year' +%s)"
    "$(date --date '1 April this year' +%s)"
    "$(date --date '1 July this year' +%s)"
    "$(date --date '1 October this year' +%s)"
)

extracted_date='14 June 2023'

extracted_time="$(date --date "${extracted_date}" +%s)"

for time_in_seconds in ${known_dates[@]}; do
    if (( extracted_time >= time_in_seconds )); then
        echo "after $(date --date "@${time_in_seconds}" +'%d %B %Y')"
    else
        echo "before $(date --date "@${time_in_seconds}" +'%d %B %Y')"
    fi
done
```

### Expected result

With `extracted_date='14 June 2023'`:

```
1 April 2023
```

### Update

The list of known dates could also change in the future, for example for a financial year where some of the months are in one year and other months are in the next year.

Comment: How would you do it on paper?

Comment: Since all dates in question relate to the same year, I would us %j instead of %s, i.e. operate on "day in year". Then I would calculate the **absolute value** of the difference between `extracted_data` and each of the reference dates, and in the course of doing this, get the minimum date.

Comment: Sorry, yes I neglected to mention that closest match should be from the past, not the future. Have updated question to show example of an expected result.

Comment: what if there is no 'closest' date 'from the past'? what if there are duplicated 'closest' dates?

Comment: If there's no closest date from the past, should probably show an error, but I haven't got that far yet. And not sure what could be considered a duplicate 'closest' date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- if there are no 'past' dates then the `extracted_date` is also our 'closest' date
- duplicate 'closest' dates (ie, we see the same 'past' date more than once) will be reported once

Go ahead and generate epoch/secs and date with a single `date` call:

```
$ known_dates=(
    "$(date --date '1 January this year' +'%s %d %B %Y')"
    "$(date --date '1 April this year' +'%s %d %B %Y')"
    "$(date --date '1 July this year' +'%s %d %B %Y')"
    "$(date --date '1 October this year' +'%s %d %B %Y')"
)

$ typeset -p known_dates
declare -a known_dates2=([0]="1672552800 01 January 2023" [1]="1680325200 01 April 2023" [2]="1688187600 01 July 2023" [3]="1696136400 01 October 2023")
```

Tweaking OP's current code:

```
extracted_date='14 June 2023'

extracted_secs="$(date --date "${extracted_date}" +%s)"

min_diff="${extracted_secs}"                                # baseline to compare epoch diffs
closest="${extracted_date}"                                 # set extracted_date as default "closest"

for secs_date in "${known_dates[@]}"; do                    # double quotes are important
    read -r secs dt <<< "${secs_date}"                      # split into epoch/secs and date

    ((diff = extracted_secs - secs))                        # calculate epoch diffs

    # if new diff is > 0 and less than previous diff then save the associated date

    if [[ "${diff}" -gt 0 && "${diff}" -lt "${min_diff}" ]]; then
        closest="${dt}"  
        min_diff="${diff}"
    fi
done

echo "closest: ${closest}"
```

This generates:

```
closest: 01 April 2023
```

---

For no dates in 'past':

```
known_dates=(
    "$(date --date '1 January next year' +'%s %d %B %Y')"
    "$(date --date '1 April next year' +'%s %d %B %Y')"
    "$(date --date '1 July this year' +'%s %d %B %Y')"
    "$(date --date '1 October this year' +'%s %d %B %Y')"
)
```

This generates:

```
closest: 14 June 2023
```

---

For duplicate 'closest' date (`1 April this year`):

```
known_dates=(
    "$(date --date '1 January this year' +'%s %d %B %Y')"
    "$(date --date '1 April this year' +'%s %d %B %Y')"
    "$(date --date '1 April this year' +'%s %d %B %Y')"
    "$(date --date '1 July this year' +'%s %d %B %Y')"
    "$(date --date '1 October this year' +'%s %d %B %Y')"
)
```

This generates:

```
closest: 01 April 2023
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. Can you please tell me more about what this line is doing? `read -r secs dt <<< "${secs_date}"` i.e. How is it splitting stuff when we have 3 whitespaces?

Comment: `secs` receives the 1st white-space delimited field (ie, the epoch/secs), `dt` receives the rest of the input (ie, 'dd mmm yyyy'); if we had used `read -r secs d m y` then `d`, `m` and `y` would be assigned the individual strings (technically `y` would be assigned the 'rest of the input); `<<< "${secs_date}"` is called a here-string and allows for the processing of a string as if it's a file (other examples: `sed 's/source/target/g' <<< "string_instead_of_file"`, `awk '{some awk script}" <<< "string_instead_of_file"`)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a method to "pick" the date it matches closest to from the list?

"Closest" means that the interval between the dates is the smallest. The method consists of computing absolute values of intervals between each pair of dates, filtering out dates in the future, and picking the smallest interval.

> Is this possible in bash?

Sure it is.

```
known_dates=(
    "$(date --date '1 January this year' +%s)"
    "$(date --date '1 April this year' +%s)"
    "$(date --date '1 July this year' +%s)"
    "$(date --date '1 October this year' +%s)"
)
extracted_date='14 June 2023'
extracted_time="$(date --date "${extracted_date}" +%s)"
printf "%s\n" "${known_dates[@]}" |
   # compute differences. pick only dates in the past
   awk -v extracted_time=$extracted_time '{$1-=extracted_time} $1<0' |
   # sort numerically
   sort -n |
   # pick the closest
   tail -n1 |
   # re-add difference
   awk -v extracted_time=$extracted_time '{$1+=extracted_time} 1' |
   # pass to date for output formatting
   xargs -I{} date -d @{} +'%-d %B %Y'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You might have to walk me through some of the `awk` and the `xargs` though...

Answer (score 1):

As the list of possible matches are all first days of a quarter, just in case this is a fixed precondition, you can use `date +%q` to get the quarter (`1`...`4`), then construct the first day of it computationally (multiply by `3` and subtract `2` to get the first month, set `1` as the day, and add `this year`).

```
extracted_date='14 June 2023'
date -d "$(($(date -d "$extracted_date" +%q)*3-2))/1 this year" +'%e %B %Y'
```

```
 1 April 2023
```

Comment: You could take the year from the extracted_date instead of assuming "this year".

Comment: @glennjackman I tried to replicate OP's list of known_dates which also featured "this year". But for the more general case, yes, making an output depend solely on explicit inputs is a much more "functional", thus cleaner approach.